# Eclipse Ivy resolve before build

Tags: eclipse, ivy, spring-tool-suite

When I open a project (or a java working set) in eclipse STS, my project builds automatically but the ivy doesn't resolve. therefore i must wait till the build has finished, then ivy resolve, then build again.

Can the ivy resolve be triggered before a build/when the project is opened and before the build as this is such a waste of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse ...
Go to Window -> Preferences.
Within the Ivy section go to the "Workspace Resolver" tab.
 
Then ensure the "On project opening trigger resolve on every other project" is ticked.

This will ensure whenever a project is opened all projects will be resolved.